# Responsive menu items disappearing

Tags: html, css

I have a sample menu that I am toying with and although it is correct in desktop view, if i view in small window 480px, when i hover away from the last item in the .has-children class, the items from About to Contact disappear. It's as though the menu isn't big enough when i hover away.

I have attached in a snippet and would appreciate any help you can give me. I have been trying to modify the .has-children class and have made no headway.

Many thanks

[Codepen layout](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRYrZE)

```
.has-children ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      nav ul li:hover ul,
      .has-children ul .has-children:hover ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
```

```css
html,body,nav, ul, li, a, span{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
body{
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:16px;
}
nav ul {
  background-color:#444;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
nav ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li a{
  padding:.8rem 1rem;
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#f9f9f9;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background:rgba(0,0,0, .25);
}

.arrow{
  font-family:FontAwesome;
  float:right;
}
.arrow-down::after{
  content:"\f107";
}
.arrow-right::after{
  content:"\f105";
}


@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .has-children ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }
      nav ul li:hover ul,
      .has-children ul .has-children:hover ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .has-children ul li a {
        padding-left: 2rem;
      }
      .has-children ul .has-children ul a {
        padding-left: 3rem;
      }
      nav ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
      .arrow-down::after {
        content: "\f107";
      }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:480px){
  nav ul{
    flex-direction:row;
/*     justify-content:flex-end; */
  }
  nav ul li{
    position:relative;
    flex:1 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
  }
  .has-children ul, .has-children ul .has-children ul{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
  }
  .has-children ul .has-children ul{
    left:100%;
    top:0;
  }
  nav ul li:hover ul,  .has-children ul .has-children:hover ul{
     display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Home
      <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
      </a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item - 1 </a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Item - 2 </a></li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Item - 3
          <span class="arrow arrow-down arrow-right"></span>
          </a>
           <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item - 1 </a></li>    
            <li><a href="#">Item - 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item - 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item - 4 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item - 5 </a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item - 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item - 5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: When viewing the inlined example on StackOverflow, it acts as intended (the menu is initially collapsed on narrower screen widths). Can you check if your actual implementation is the same as the example you provided? Since the example seems to be working a-ok : )

Comment: @Kano When I run snippet here and go responsive by shrinking the browser, the menu stays the same and dosen't resize att all. Should i do codepen layout because the problem i think would be more obvious. It is definately the same code i am using that i posted. thanks

Comment: @Kano Many apologies, you are correct. I shall modify question to allow for this. Thanks

Comment: @Kano I have updated code in snippet to correct code for uncollapsed. So my question is still valid as i posted. Many thanks

Comment: In your css media query change your `min-width` to `min-device-width` and try.

Comment: @Dragon Manu becomes unresponsive. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You want to make your website responsive the best and easiest tool to make your website responsive is **BootStrap** why don't you use that way.
 Here is the link to download bootstrap file
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

from this link download the **complied css and js**. it includes two files one is css file and the other is javascript file and the way to include these files in html header tag like code below

```
<head>
  <title> Website Title </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.css">
  <script src="filename.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here the link for collapsing navigation bar
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp and 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

**I Hope This Will Help You**

Comment: I've ran out of votes for the day, but know if I had one, this would be down voted.

Comment: @Sheraz Thanks for that. However I am familiar with bootstrap but I am trying to learn the basics before I tackle more advanced html. My problem cannot be that difficult to solve for experts? Thanks

Comment: @Xoog got you covered. Downvoted for a) adding unnecessary bloat to a project with bootstrap and b) referencing w3schools.